# Evaluating $\sec(\tan^{-1}\sqrt3)$ exactly

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> Find the exact value of the expression
> $$\sec(\tan^{-1}\sqrt3)$$

I'm confused about how to start the problem and what quadrant to use.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\sec^{2}(x) = \tan^{2}(x) + 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The best way to start is to recall the definition:
$$
\sec x=\frac1{\cos x}.
$$
Since the range of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is $[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$ we conclude that the value of cosine is positive. Hence:
$$
\frac1{\cos x}=\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}=2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\tan^{-1}\sqrt(3)$ is in quad  $1$ ( since $\sqrt(3) > 0$), so $\sec(\tan^{-1}\sqrt(3))=\frac{2}{1}~(>0)$.